# tcolorbox: several row heights at tcbitemize

Tags: tcolorbox

I have a whole-page tcbitemize-structure and in that there are some rows, that are higher or maybe less high than the others.

*What do I have to set that the height adapts to the content?*

*The box with the red font should be higher, the others should adjust their heights.*

[image]

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}   
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=1, 
raster rows=8, % I think this value can't be calculatet automatically
%raster equal height=none, 
raster height=\textheight,% <---- needed and creates the problem
raster width=4cm, 
% Just for a test (automatic adjustment would be better), but no effect if 'raster height=\textheight'  is used: 
%raster row 2/.style={height=5cm},% Test  
]
\tcbitem L1
\tcbitem[coltext=red] L2a \\ L2b\\ L2c\\ L2d \\ L2e \\ L2f \\ L2g
\tcbitem L3
\tcbitem L4
\tcbitem L5
\tcbitem L6
\tcbitem L7
\tcbitem L8
\end{tcbitemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You want box L2 taller and all other boxes equally shorter?

Comment: Yes, in that way.

Comment: Seems one has to do the comparison and re-calculation manually, using box array provided by tcolorbox library `magazine`.

Comment: Aha, I have never worked with that.